# Use Macro in excel to edit cell values in another table?

Tags: excel, worksheet, vba

I have an Excel project which contains 3 worksheets, namely "Unhealthy Foods" "Healthy Foods" and "Meal"

The two food tables contain a list of foods along with their their fat, protein and carbohydrate content. Using that data, their calories per 100 grams are also calculated. These foods are divided into 3 sub-headings: Foods, snacks and drinks. I want to create a macro which will be launched using an "Add to Meal" button next to each food item on each table which will copy the row's content to the first available row in the "Meal" class.

Is it possible for this to be done? If so, how?

Comment: Is it essential to have a button to click?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue (in my opinion) with using buttons to refer to cells on a worksheet is that buttons are objects on the worksheet which makes getting their position in terms of column / row quite tricky.

Here is the *brute force* approach if you want to use buttons. Suppose in `Healthy Foods` you have the folllowing:

```
     A         B      C          D
1    Item      Fat    Protein    Sugar
2    Apple     0      50         5       |Add To Menu|  <-- this is a commandbutton called **Apple**
3    Snickers  100    0          100     |Add to Menu|  <-- this is a commandbutton called **snickers**
```

The following code will copy the details to next available row in `Meal` (NB - I assume Meal is same table format as shown above)

```
Private Sub Apple_Click()
    AddMealToMenu Range("A2") //For each button you must specify range where item is in table
End Sub

Sub AddMealToMenu(ref As Range)
    Dim mealItem As Range
    Set mealItem = Range(ref, ref.Offset(0, 3))
    mealItem.Copy Destination:=GetNextFreeRow
End Sub

Function GetNextFreeRow() As Range
    With Worksheets("Meal")
        If .Range("A2") = vbNullString Then
            Set GetNextFreeRow = .Range("A2")
        Else
            Set GetNextFreeRow = .Range("A1").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0)
        End If
    End With
End Function
```

For **Snickers** you would need to add simialr code for Apple i.e.

```
Private Sub Snickers_Click()
    AddMealToMenu Range("A3")
End Sub
```

If this works for you, fine, but it may take some setting up and is a brute force approach.

Comment: Worked perfectly thanks :)
Another question, lets say i'm looking for the food with the most protein, I know I can use the MAX formula to find out which food has the highest protein levels, but how do I make the cell display the name of the food rather than it's protein level?

Comment: Do you mean have a button on the sheet that you press and it highlights the food with the most protein?

Comment: No I have a small table at the bottom of the worksheet which needs to get the name of the food with the highest protein by means of a formula, not a macro

Comment: @Remnant So for example, I have the foods: Oranges, apples, almonds and pizza, one below another in a worksheet, and in the cell next to each food is it's protein content. I can use the MAX formula in the table which I spoke about in the above comment which would look something like this:
=MAX(D10,D11,D12,D13,D14)
The problem with this is that the cell will show the highest protein content in the form of a number (in this case 2100, which is the value of D11), not the name of the food which has that as the protein content (which is an apple)

Comment: Assuming your foods are in C10:C14 and protein in D10:D14 then try the following: `=INDIRECT(ADDRESS(MATCH(MAX(D10:D14),D10:D14,0)+9,3))`

Comment: @Remnant What if my foods are A10:A14 and proteins are in D10:D14?

Comment: Change the `3` in the above formula to `1`